# Appropriate use of "reaching" when the subject gets smaller and not bigger

Tags: subjects, appropriate

Is it OK to say that something reaches 1/5th of its original size? Like in the following sentence:

"Not only that, but the output images are also highly compressed, sometimes reaching (up?) to 1/5th of their original size..."

Comment: I wouldn't use "up" or "to" in that sentence. Putting "only" in the same place reads naturally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Oxford Online English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reach), definition 2.1:

> Attain or extend to (a specified point, level, or condition):
>
> unemployment reached a peak in 1933
>
> [NO OBJECT]: in its native habitat it will reach to about 6 m in height

Attain certainly can mean both directions, so I think it can *technically* be used in that fashion.

As far as should?  Given that smaller is *better* in this case, I think it's reasonable.  Certainly it is common to say:

> I reached my goal weight of 140 lbs

which certainly wasn't reached from a lower weight in the majority of instances.  For your particular usage, "shrinking" is probably more common (emphasizing the reduction in size), but I think "reach" is perfectly fine.

I would not use "reached" to mean regressed (ie, got worse).

Comment: Agreed. Wikipedia has 'The laws of thermodynamics dictate that absolute zero cannot be reached using only thermodynamic means', but there is a real achievement involved here. I think 'gets down to' usually sounds less incongruous.

Comment: Sure (shrinks is similar certainly).  But for image compression software, shrinking is certainly it's goal...

Comment: With that example, 'sometimes, a size just 20% of the original is achieved'.

Answer (score 3):

Though the underlying word picture of *[reach](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reach&allowed_in_frame=0)* is *extending* or *stretching out*, it has embraced metaphoric applications for a long time:

> Old English *ræcan*, *reccan* "reach out, stretch out, extend, hold
>   forth,"
>   also "succeed in touching, succeed in striking; address,
>   speak to,"
>   also "offer, present, give, grant,"
>   from West Germanic
>   *raikjan "stretch out the hand"
>   (cognates: Old Frisian *reka*, Middle Dutch *reiken*, Dutch *reiken*, Old High German and German *reichen*),
>   from Proto-Germanic *raikijanau,
>   perhaps from PIE root *reig- "to
>   stretch out"
>   (cognates: Sanskrit *rjyati* "he stretches himself," *riag*
>   "torture" (by racking);
>   Greek *oregein* "to reach, extend;" Lithuanian
>   *raižius* "to stretch oneself;" Old Irish *rigim* "I stretch").
>
> <sub>etymonline.com</sub>

As other answers have indicated, the current definition seems to be quite consistent with attaining a goal or hitting a target--even if the target implies the restriction to a fractional proportion.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go along with Joe's suggestion and use "sometimes **shrinking** to...". It follows naturally from "highly compressed", I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely wouldn't say "up to".

If you're making something smaller, you don't say "up".

I'd have put something like "down to as little as 1/5", rather than "up to", unless you rephrase to something more like "with compression ratios up to 5:1" (since the compression ratio is higher when the end result is smaller).